# Insert New data into multiple tables with Foreign Key simultaneously in One query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

**tblDepartment**:

```
Id    Name
```

and

**tblEmployee**:

```
Id    FullName    Dept_ID
```

`Dept_ID` is a foreign key for `tblDepartment`

I want to insert a new record into both tables.

I tried this:

```
declare @id int 

insert dbo.tblDepartment
   select Name='Name1'

select id = scope_Identity()

insert dbo.tblEmployee 
   select FullName = 'Name1' 

select Dept_Id=@id
select Id=@id
```

However, this is not working. I searched through other posts, but they contain solutions for inserting existing data from one table into another, not creating a new record. How can I do this in one query?

Comment: sql server...............

Answer (score 3):

You need to use variables properly along with column lists for inserts.  Assuming you are using SQL Server:

```
declare @id int ;

insert dbo.tblDepartment(Name)
    select 'Name1';
select @id = scope_Identity();

insert dbo.tblEmployee(FullName, Dept_Id)
    select 'Name1', @id;
```

Also, `scope_identity()` is okay for learning about such id's.  The safe way to really get this information is to use the `output` clause.

Comment: @NeerajVerma . . . You cannot insert into two tables with a single `insert`.  You can wrap these in a single transaction, and so commit the changes to the database at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @id int 

insert dbo.tblDepartment(Name)
select 'Name1'
-- Don't insert any other statements before next line...
select @id=scope_Identity()


insert dbo.tblEmployee(Fullname, Dept_ID) 
select 'Name1',  @id
```